# Get Started With Microsoft Fabric - Error in Training Module

Tags: apache-spark, microsoft-fabric

I'm going through the "Get Started with Microsoft Fabric" training course, and I've run into a problem that won't allow me to continue with the exercise. Wondering if anyone else has encountered this, and if you figured out a solution.

I'm in the seventh unit of "Use Apache Spark in Microsoft Fabric", at the "Work with tables and SQL" section. The exercise has me enter this code:

```
# Create a new table
df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("salesorders")

# Get the table description
spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED salesorders").show(truncate=False)
```

but when I run this, I get this error:

**NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 2
1 # Create a new table
----> 2 df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("salesorders")
4 # Get the table description
5 spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED salesorders").show(truncate=False)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined**

I've done everything in the course up until this point, and haven't skipped over any sections, so can't understand why this is failing. Have they (Microsoft) omitted a step?

I've tried googling the error, but have not found anything that is particular to this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, looks like you have not defined 'df'. First try defining 'df' and then create table

```
# Create a DataFrame from a list of data
data = [("John", 25), ("Jane", 30), ("Mike", 40)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "age"])

# Create a new table
df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("salesorders")

# Get the table description
spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED salesorders").show(truncate=False)
```